# Throwing Exceptions in ContinueWith new System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library, console-application

I have the following sample code:

```
public static void Main() 
{
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        string s = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Test.zip");
        return s;
    });

    var c = t.ContinueWith((_) => 
    {
       _myTimer = new Timer(TestItem, null, 2500, 2500);
    });

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void TestItem(object data)
{
    try 
    {
        throw new Exception("My Test Error");
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    {
        _myTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        throw;
    }
}
```

How do I go about catching the error thrown from TestItem. Is there a way I can monitor TestItem for errors?

At the moment in visual studio it gives me a unhandled exception, how can I handle it?

I was wondering if any one could help or point me in the right direction.

Comment: The problem is with the fact that `TestItem` will be scheduled on an arbitrary thread-pool thread. What .NET version are you on?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov using 4.5

Answer (score 1):

You can't catch it, TestItem() runs on a thread-pool thread long after the task completed.  AppDomain.UnhandledException is as good as it gets.  If you don't want the program to terminate then you *must* catch and handle the exception inside TestItem().

Task.Delay() would be a sane alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is something entirely different:

```
static async Task TestItem()
{
    while (true) {
     try 
     {
         await Task.Delay(2500);
         throw new Exception("My Test Error");
     } 
     catch (Exception) 
     {
        //TODO for you: handle
     }
    }
}
```

And just call that method in `Main`:

```
TestItem(); //no await
```

Your timer can fire multiple times which is a bug. All of that goes away with modern API usage. Throw the existing approach away.

Comment: When I try the above it only fires once, if I remove the the throw new exception. At some point within a time frame, TestItem can throw an exception, this is what I want to try and handle when it occurs

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted it to fire once. I now wrapped a loop around this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = t.ContinueWith(tk => 
{
    _myTimer = new Timer(TestItem, null, 2500, 2500);

    //you can check the type of exception, etc
    //if(tk.Exception is AggregateException) //etc
    var message = tk.Exception.Message;

}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: Any comments on how this would answer the question instead of just posting code.

Comment: The comments are in the code which answer his question.